# In a series of logical ANDs, if one AND fails are the remaining ANDs performed? C++

Tags: c++

In the below example will the comparison between `a` and `c` be executed or will it be skipped? I would assume the answer is no because the value of `valid` has already been determined since if any comparison is `false` in this expression the resulting value of `valid` is `false`, but I don't actually know if that's true.

```
int i = 10, b = 20, c, 30;
bool valid = (i > b && a < c);
```

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: It's something related to short-circuit. Though I don't write c++, I think c++ has the same mechanism.

Comment: TLDR; it depends. If `operator&&` is overloaded all comparisons will be evaluated. If it's not overloaded the evaluation is short-circuited. That's the reason `operator&&` and `operator||` shouldn't be overloaded as AND resp. OR operators.